# Connecting to an IRC server using C#

Tags: c#, irc, tcpclient

I've been trying my hand at a minimalistic IRC bot, but I can never get a connection to work.

I'm doing this via a TcpClient object, which I've seen used in other such projects and those reportedly work.

Here's the code.

```
private string server = "irc.freenode.net";
private int port = 6667;
private string nick = "testingsharpbot";
private string channel = "testblablabla";

private TcpClient irc;

public ConfigForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.irc = new TcpClient(this.server, this.port);

    using(NetworkStream stream = irc.GetStream()){
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream) {NewLine = "\r\n", AutoFlush = true}) {
                sw.WriteLine("NICK " + this.nick);
                sw.WriteLine("JOIN " + this.channel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I wait a bit and then do a /whois on the nickname, but I always get the same reply: user does not exist.

As far as I'm aware, the TcpClient makes the connection and I can then use the NetWorkStream instance to read and write to that connection.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

At first, I suggest you taking a look in the appropiate RFC:

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2812.html

Look at Connection Registration. You need to follow this steps to get a connection:

1. Pass message
2. Nick message
3. User message

You're missing the USER command.